# Can I setup cpanel in openshift app?

Tags: openshift, cpanel

I’ve an openshift php app. I do want to setup cpanel for that. Therefore, is it feasible? If yes then please advise just how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not install cpanel on OpenShift, partially because you do not have access to the entire filesystem.  Also, you are not managing as many resources, so you don't need it.  You should be fine using git/sftp/phpmyadmin.